# Django ORM - Adjust field value on return

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model that stores user-entered database password. As my app needs to connect to these databases. The password is encrypted in the database. However, when it is retrieved I need to apply a `decrypt` function to the password field. Where can I do that so that it is only applied when querying the database, not when saving the field.

Here is my model:

```
class Databases(models.Model):
    """
    Handles the storing of database connections
    """
    # Initialize the encryption class
    e = Encryption()
    # Our unique id for the database
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # Database name to display to the user
    database_display_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True, unique=True)
    # Database name
    database_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    # Database status
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)
    # The host name
    host = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    # The default port
    port = models.IntegerField(default=3306)
    # The username for the database
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # The password for the database
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    # Set the database type
    database_type = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True, default="mysql")
    # Timestamps
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    event_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)

    def get_password(self, obj):
        print("Retrieving")
        return Databases.e.decrypt(obj.password)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        On save, update timestamps
        """
        # If the record does not currently exist in the database
        if not self.id:
            self.created_at = timezone.now()
        self.updated_at = timezone.now()
        # Encrypt the password
        self.password = Databases.e.encrypt(self.password)

        return super(Databases, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'databases'
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class DatabasesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Databases
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the get_password method a `property` of the `Databases` class:

```
    @property
    def get_password(self):
        print("Retrieving")
        return self.e.decrypt(self.password)
```

then you'll be able to use it in your serializer:

```
class DatabasesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    get_password = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Databases
        fields = ('get_password', ...,)
```

Comment: I think I may have created some confusion: I'm trying to overwrite the field password with self.e.decrypt(self.password), so that whenever the password field is used it will show the results of self.e.decrypt(self.password)

Comment: I'd recommend against storing plain-text passwords in the database, if someone gains unauthorized access all your DBs will be compromised. Anyway, if you want to store them in plain text, why bother with encryption when saving in the first place?